# I got an error when exporting data from R

Tags: r, export

When I wanted to export my results from R with this code,

```
write.table(imp, "c:/immp.txt", sep="\t")
```

I got this error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""mids"" to a data.frame
```

Sorry for a simple question,I am new to R.
Thanks for your help

Comment: use `write.table()` to export a `data.frame`. what code did you use to build `imp`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks HubertL I used this:write.table(imp, "c:/immp.txt", sep="\t")

Comment: @Ava, the reason @HubertL asks  (I think) is because we cannot tell what class or data type `imp` is. The error message that you show above is because write.table expects a data.frame, and `imp` cannot be forced (coerced) into  `data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks epi99 for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to export a "mids" object, as opposed to a data frame. You'll need to convert it to a data frame before using write.table, which you should be able to do with complete():

```
impframe <- complete( imp, action = "long", include = TRUE )
```

Adjust the options as necessary for your data. Then try your write.table command.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer based on your answer I found it

Comment: out <- capture.output(imp)
cat( out, file="imputation.txt", sep="\n", append=TRUE)