# Creating an r dataframe of gam models

Tags: r, dataframe, gam

If I fit three different gam models as follows:

```
library(mgcv)
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(count = rpois(100,1),
                 pred1 = rnorm(100, 10, 1), 
                 pred2 = rnorm(100, 0, 1), 
                 pred3 = rnorm(100, 0, 1))

m1 <- gam(count ~ s(pred1),
             data = dat, 
             family = poisson(link="log"), 
             method = "REML", 
             select = TRUE)

m2 <- gam(count ~ s(pred2),
          data = dat, 
          family = poisson(link="log"), 
          method = "REML", 
          select = TRUE)

m3 <- gam(count ~ s(pred3),
          data = dat, 
          family = poisson(link="log"), 
          method = "REML", 
          select = TRUE)
```

And then try and put them into a single dataframe:

```
models <- data.frame(m = c(m1,m2,m3))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"family"’ to a data.frame
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I want to create structure that I can loop over to make some predictions from.

Comment: It is better try `models <- list(m1,m2,m3)` then you can create functions to make predictions.

Comment: If all you want is a structure to loop over, why not a list?  `myList <- list(m1, m2, m3)` then `myAnswer <- lapply(myList, function(x) ....)`.  If you really need the models in a data.frame, `broom` might be a good start...

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37149696/i-got-an-error-when-exporting-data-from-r

Comment: And which package are you using?  `gam`?  `mgvc`?  Another?

Comment: Thanks. I've added mgcv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgcv/versions/1.8-31/topics/gam) indicate, the return value of `mgcv::gam` is an object of `gam` class. This [**`gamObject`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgcv/versions/1.8-31/topics/gamObject) inherits from base R's class objects (`lm` and `glm`) and so includes many underlying elements that cannot be easily binded into the two dimensions of a `data frame`:

> **Fitted Gam Object**
>
> A fitted GAM object returned by function `gam` and of class "gam"
> inheriting from classes "glm" and "lm". Method functions `anova`,
> `logLik`, `influence`, `plot`, `predict`, `print`, `residuals` and `summary` exist
> for this class.

Usually to retrieve estimates from these model objects, you would run `summary` to return a list of named elements such as coefficients, residuals, etc. From there, extract the needed components that can be either a vector, matrix, or list into data frames. Note: due to varying nature of lengths and types of underlying components, there is no simple method to extract *all* estimates of model to a data frame.

You will have to ask yourself:

- What specific estimates of model do I want in a data frame?
- Do I keep *all* three model estimates in *one* data frame or use a list of data frames?
- What indicator data (data, formula, etc.) to store to distinguish form others?

  [StackOverflow R posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+regression+coefficients+data+frame) contain many examples of how to extract model estimates like coefficients into data frames.

One implementation is to define a method to extract model estimates with input parameter being a formula which appears to be only difference between all three models.

```
run_gam_models <- function(my_formula) {
      fit <- gam(my_formula,
                 data = dat, 
                 family = poisson(link="log"), 
                 method = "REML", 
                 select = TRUE)

      results <- summary(fit)

      df <- data.frame(results$coefficients, ...)
      return(df)
}

# LIST OF DATA FRAMES
coeffs_df_list <- sapply(names(dat)[-1], function(col) {
       f <- as.formula(paste0("count ~ ", col))
       run_gam_models(f)
}, simplify = FALSE)

# INDIVIDUAL DATA FRAMES
coeffs_df_list$pred1
coeffs_df_list$pred2
coeffs_df_list$pred3
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/YEGQ27959)</kbd> *(using `glm`)*